# Why is rails server listing on tcp

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a project which is an updated version of a new project. Using vagrant to load virtual environment and when i run

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rails s
```

The following is returned:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.6.0 (ruby 2.3.3-p222), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

When i visit the browser I have tried localhost:3000 and 127.0.0.1:3000 but keep getting:

```
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

On the previous version of this project on a different repository loaded it was accessible via these URL's. This project has been updated to Rails 5 but dont know why it is listening on TCP rather than HTTP. Any suggestions?

Comment: HTTP is a higher level protocol which runs on top of TCP. TCP provides a reliable low-level connection which automatically handles retransmissions if packets are lost, etc. TCP doesn't define anything about the format of the data that you send over it. HTTP works on top of that, defining a standardized data format for requesting resources from and sending resources to an HTTP server.

Comment: Is port 3000 on your host mapped to port 3000 on the vagrant VM? Provide any vagrant configuration if possible. Additionally, if you are sending requests to the server inside the VM, the rails server process must be bound to `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost` otherwise it will not allow "remote" connections (from your machine, which is external to the vagrant VM). You can use `rails s -b 0.0.0.0` to bind to `0.0.0.0` and allow external connections. Be advised this will expose the rails server to any connection that can reach it.

Comment: are you using docker. If using docker , export port  3000

Answer (score 1):

As it has been already suggested, make sure that the server is bounden to 0.0.0.0 so that all interfaces can access it.

You might try:

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```